# Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine Oledb provider in SSIS

Tags: ms-access, ssis, oledb

I am not able to see Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine Oledb provider in SSIS and I'm using MS Office 2013.

How to re-solve this?

Comment: Are you using updated version of MS Office?

Answer (score 11):

You are missing the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010.

Download it here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Install it on your dev-client and on your servers. After the installation has completed, you should see the Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine OLEDB provider in your Visual Studio's connection wizard.

Comment: No problem, I'm always glad to help. Btw: It would be nice, if you'd mark my answer.

Comment: I have installed it and still cannot see Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine Oledb. What am I missing?

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin Try install 32 bit version, it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

I also had same issue. I could not find Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine oledb even after installing Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016.
Then I installed both versions: Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 and Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016, now the issue is resolved.