# Choice "microsoft office 12.0 Access database engine OLE DB Provider" I don't find it in crystal report

Tags: c#, ms-access, crystal-reports

My computer - programs installed

- microsoft access database engine 2016
- visual studio 2019
- SAP Crystal Reports
- Microsoft Office 2019

---

I follwoed these steps:

> Field Explorer > Database Fields WINDOW(Database Expert) -> OLE DB
>   (ADO)  Choice "microsoft office 12.0 Access database engine OLE DB
>   Provider"

I don't find "microsoft office 12.0 Access database engine OLE DB Provider" listed.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Did you try selecting the "Jet" provider? That is the Access provider. give it a go, once you select it you will browse to the Access db you are using.

Comment: yes , not working

Comment: i need to add "microsoft office 12.0 Access database engine OLE DB Provider" , but i don't know how  to add this choice @SimonWilson

Comment: Have you followed [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37696487/microsoft-office-12-0-access-database-engine-oledb-provider-in-ssis) instructions? Or you can just download the engine from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255)